# Integration: product containing square root.

Tags: integration

How can I integrate the following expression?

[image]

I have tried using u-substitution, but I am having problems with integrating the entire expression. So far, I have the following: 
[image]

Any help on this is highly appreciated!

Comment: You're basically there… the integral you have can now be written as $-V_0/(k\sqrt{2})\int u^{1/2}du$, which I assume you can manage.

Comment: And after you take the integral, you will want to substitute $u=1+e^{-kt}$ back in to get the result as a function of $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it. $u=1+e^{-kt}$ and $du=-ke^{-kt}dt$, so $dt = -\frac{du}{k}$ where $k$ is just a constant. Rewrite this and you have $\int \sqrt{u}\frac{du}{-k}$, which I bet you know how to integrate!

Comment: Thank you! Figured it out, I think.